# How can i programmatically click a external Application Using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I have created a test software to test our product, but in some cases other customer provide there API/Tool and etc... to test there specific parameter.

I want is to click the button on other the application (Automatically Click).

Basically we want it so the operator will not click the wrong button even there have a work instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'------------------------------FORM-----------------------------------------------

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        LeftClick()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CommandType.Text = "Start" Then
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            CommandType.Text = "Stop"
        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            CommandType.Text = "Start"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MoveMouse(300, 75)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
    End Sub

End Class
```

'------------------------------MODULE----------------------------------------------

```
Module Module1

    Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Integer
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
    Public Structure POINTAPI
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
    End Structure
    Public Function GetX() As Integer
        : Dim n As POINTAPI
        GetCursorPos(n)
        GetX = n.x
    End Function
    Public Function GetY() As Integer
        Dim n As POINTAPI
        GetCursorPos(n)
        GetY = n.y
    End Function
    Public Sub LeftClick()
        LeftDown()
        LeftUp()
    End Sub
    Public Sub LeftDown()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub LeftUp()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub MiddleClick()
        MiddleDown()
        MiddleUp()
    End Sub
    Public Sub MiddleDown()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub MiddleUp()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub RightClick()
        RightDown()
        RightUp()
    End Sub
    Public Sub RightDown()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub RightUp()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub MoveMouse(ByVal xMove As Integer, ByVal yMove As Integer)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xMove, yMove, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub SetMousePos(ByVal xPos As Integer, ByVal yPos As Integer)
        SetCursorPos(xPos, yPos)
    End Sub
End Module
```

This will allow you to Left click, Right click and move cursor base on X and Y Axis.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr   

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim hWndMsgBox, hWndButton As Long

    hWndMsgBox = FindWindow("#32770", "About")
    If hWndMsgBox Then hWndButton = FindWindowEx(hWndMsgBox, 0&, "Button", "OK")
    If hWndButton Then SendMessage(hWndButton, BM_CLICK, 0&, 0&) 
End Sub
```

Comment: I've experience using that code to click the button using the address caught using Spy++ or something,i bit lose using it but i will try it again =D