# VBA Excel - Stop user from being able to use the mouse but allow the user to stop or pause the script

Tags: excel, vba, mouse

Good afternoon everyone.

*Note- I have looked for a couple of days for the answer to this question.

I have a bit of code that controls a separate piece of software to enter data.
I can not access the scripting side of this software, so I will just leave that bit out.

I have the following working.
Mouse movement.
Mouse Click.
Data input.

The only problem here is that while the script is running, I can still move the mouse manually. Which in turn can cause it to click on something wrong.

I know that
"BlockInput = True" deactivates mouse and keyboard.
This stops me from using the keyboard or it would work great.

"Application.Interactive = False" makes the cursor do the thinking thing.
This stops the program from clicking on the items I need to be clicked and still lets me use the mouse.

I hope this makes sense. This script will only be temporary until I get scripting access to the software.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to move the mouse at all? If you need to click something, you can just send a `PostMessage` to its message pump with the coordinates.

Comment: @Comintern : Because I have never heard of that command before. I will look into that. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a Windows API function. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055749/4088852) is VB.NET, but it should be fairly trivial to convert to VBA.